# Login popup for password protected page authorization loaded in iframe

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

In the password protected website it load authentication box too much fast..Is there any way to load it slowly ...is there any code for that in .htaccess file which load box slowly ..

Below my HTACCESS Code

```
AuthUserFile /home/user4015/public_html/iptrackercheck/.htpasswd 
AuthType Basic AuthName "Suspicious activity detected on your IP address due to harmful virus installed in your computer. Call Toll Free now 1-888-442-8745 for any assistance.…" 
<files "report.php">Require valid-user </files> 
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpe?g|gif|css|js)$"> 
Satisfy Any Allow from all 
</FilesMatch> 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.html [L]
```

My HTML code is

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='iptrackercheck.aasthasolutions.com'">; 
<script src="Javascript/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<iframe src="report.php" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Varsha, are you talking about password protected site authentication  or login authentication?.. and what you have done so far?

Comment: its about password protected site

Comment: have you implemented some code for that?

Comment: yes i implement

Comment: Below is my htacces  file code

Comment: put it in your qustion.. so I can judge in correct way

Comment: AuthUserFile /home/user4015/public_html/iptrackercheck/.htpasswd


AuthType Basic

AuthName "Suspicious activity detected on your IP address due to harmful virus installed in your computer. Call Toll Free now 1-888-442-8745 for any assistance.…"

<files "report.php">

Require valid-user

</files>

<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpe?g|gif|css|js)$">

  Satisfy Any

  Allow from all

</FilesMatch>



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.html [L]

Comment: this is only for one `report.php` file right?

Comment: yes absolutely right

Comment: ok,,, can you give me HTML code from where you redirect to that file?

Comment: <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='http://iptrackercheck.aasthasolutions.com'">
  <script src="Javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <iframe src="report.php" width="1" height="1"></iframe>

Comment: report.php load in iframe

Comment: I can provides some hints.. not absolute code.. is it okey?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using bootstrap popup for ask username or password if first ajax request send error.

I am not sure its working 100% but this is my idea it may be help to you.

**Consider your code in index.php.**

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='iptrackercheck.aasthasolutions.com'">; 
<script src="Javascript/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="" width="1" height="1" id="protected_iframe"></iframe>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="login_btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**Your Script file or inline HTML script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#protected_iframe").length>1)
    {
        // validate already authorized or not by send get request
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "report.php"
            success:function(data){
                // if already authorised then set src in iframe;
                $("#protected_iframe").attr("src","report.php");
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,error){
                //get authorization error the display model for login
                console.log(status);
                $("#myModal").modal();
            }
        });
    }
    $("#login_btn").click(function(){
        // you can do validation here for username and password required
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "report.php",
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                // set username and password in authorization header
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa($("#username").val() + ":" + $("#password").val()));
            },
            success: function (data){
                // if success then load report.php in iframe
                 $("#protected_iframe").attr("src","report.php");
            },
            error: functioon(xhr,status,error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: my problem is about password protected .htaccess  file